# playwright headless chromium can't find selector, but finds it in UI mode

Tags: python, chromium, e2e-testing, playwright, playwright-python

### What I'm trying to do

I am doing some e2e testing with playwright on a webapp

### The problem

I am running into problems whenever I want to save resources with headless mode.
My playwright script is working perfectly in chromium UI mode. When encountering the first from (login), this happens:

```
[2022-03-31 07:57:38,079] [root] [ERROR] [MainThread]: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for selector "#username"
```

### What I tried

I looked for answers, but can't find anything on this issue. I have absolutely no idea why an id selector would work in UI mode, but not in headless mode. It's just html and it's also able to pass other selectors like clicking buttons to get to the login. I'm at a loss here.

Code snippet:

```
# goto voice client
await page.click(selector='[title=log_in]')
await page.wait_for_timeout(timeout=500)

# enter credentials
await page.type(selector='#username', text=self.username, delay=50)
await page.type(selector='#password', text=self.password, delay=50)
await page.wait_for_timeout(timeout=100)
```

Comment: did you check what you get in HTML ? - ie. save HTML in file and open in text editor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Headless doesn't work using Playwright and BeautifulSoup 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72887356/headless-doesnt-work-using-playwright-and-beautifulsoup-4). If not, please share a [mcve] so others can see the problem so they can help fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this similar problem where it works during headed mode but not in headless.

**What I did**

I enabled my `video` settings in `playwright.config.ts`.

```
use: {
    actionTimeout: 0,
    trace: "on-first-retry",
    viewport: null,
    launchOptions: {
      args: ["--start-maximized"],
    },
    video: "on",
  }
```

Note that in my config, the `viewport` option has a value of `null` in order to configure the `launchOptions` to have `"--start-maximized"` which allows the browsers to always be maximized during run time.

After enabling the `video` option, I restarted my test and from the generated video, I have observed that it is using a smaller screen size during run time and was unable to continue at a certain stage of the test, because it was unable to find the selector as it wasn't present.

It used a smaller screen size because during headless mode, it wasn't able to interpret the `launchOptions` and have only interpreted the `viewport` which has a `null` value. Similar raised issue: [link](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/7402).

**Workaround** - any of the following:

- change the selector(if applicable) to support bigger and smaller screen sizes
- specify the value of the viewport in the playwright config
- if the issue only occurs on a specific test, then just specify the viewport on that specific test.
  `test.use({viewport: {width: 1920, height: 1080}});`

Comment: How would I change those settings for pytest-playwright?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem as well where my test would run in headed mode but not headless mode. I had a window of Chromium open when trying to run my test and it will fail. Once I closed all Chromium windows it worked in headless mode.

Answer (score 1):

What I ran into when I saw this behavior is that when running in headless mode, the browser was failing bot detection tests on the site I was accessing. You can see this if you make sure and dump `page.content()` and inspect it in headless mode.

To get around this, you can use Playwright's Devices support to make sure and emulate a particular browser on a device when in headless mode:

https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-playwright#playwright-devices

Below is some example code from that page that configures webkit to emulate an iPhone 6. Note how you setup a `context` and call `new_page()` on it instead of the browser.

```
    webkit = playwright.webkit
    iphone = playwright.devices["iPhone 6"]
    browser = webkit.launch()
    context = browser.new_context(**iphone)
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto("http://example.com")
```

This approach passed the bot test.

Answer (score 0):

Try headed mode. `yarn playwright test --headed` or you can also configure that in your code.

```
import { test, expect, devices } from "@playwright/test";

const deviceUA = devices["Desktop Chrome"].userAgent;

test.describe("Test case", () => {
  test.use({ userAgent: deviceUA });

  test("Test case", async ({
    page,
  }) => {
     # goto voice client
     await page.click(selector='[title=log_in]')
     await page.wait_for_timeout(timeout=500)

     # enter credentials
     await page.type(selector='#username', text=self.username, delay=50)
     await page.type(selector='#password', text=self.password, delay=50)
     await page.wait_for_timeout(timeout=100)
  });
});
```

You are telling Playwright to use headed chrome in for this "Test case" where as it is using headless mode by default.