# Headless doesn't work using Playwright and BeautifulSoup 4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, headless, playwright, playwright-python

This code is working:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import time

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://www.apple.com/br/shop/product/MV7N2BE/A/airpods-com-estojo-de-recarga")
    html = page.content()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    valorAppleStore = soup.select("span.as-price-installments")[-2].get_text().replace(" à vista (10% de desconto)", '')
    print(valorAppleStore)
    browser.close()
```

But if I change `headless=True`, the code returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/ANDERSONCARVALHODELI/Documents/py/AirpodsPW.py", line 19, in <module>
    valorAppleStore = soup.select("span.as-price-installments")[-2].get_text().replace(" à vista (10% de desconto)", 
'')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I fixed this using:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import time

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://www.apple.com/br/shop/product/MV7N2BE/A/airpods-com-estojo-de-recarga")
    time.sleep(1)
    browser.close()
    
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://www.apple.com/br/shop/product/MV7N2BE/A/airpods-com-estojo-de-recarga")
    html = page.content()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    valorAppleStore = soup.select("span.as-price-installments")[-2].get_text().replace(" à vista (10% de desconto)", '')
    print(valorAppleStore)
```

But I think this is not the better choice. How do I fix this without opening the browser using `headless=False` and stick to `headless=True`?

When I `print(html)` before `soup=...`, I see:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html><html><head> <title>Page Not Found - Apple</title> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.apple.com/wss/fonts?families=SF+Pro,v1|SF+Pro+Icons,v1"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.apple.com/v/errors/c/built/styles/main.built.css" type="text/css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.apple.com/v/errors/c/built/styles/overview.built.css" type="text/css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4982/store.apple.com/shop/rs-external/rel/us/external.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4982/store.apple.com/shop/rs-globalelements/dist/us/globalelements.css"> <style>.more::after{content: "";}a.pointer, a.more, a.block span.more, button.unbutton.more{padding-right: .7em; background-image: url(https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4982/store.apple.com/shop/rs-web/2/dist/assets/as-legacy/base/link/res/more.svg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 100% 50%; background-size: 5px 9px; zoom: 1;}.as-globalfooter-directory-column-section-list a{margin-bottom: .8em; display: block}.as-globalfooter-directory-column-section-list a:last-child{margin-bottom: 0;}.as-globalfooter-mini .as-globalfooter-mini-shop a{color: #06c;}.as-globalfooter .as-globalfooter-mini-legal-copyright, .as-footnotes .as-globalfooter-mini-legal-copyright, .as-globalfooter .as-globalfooter-mini-legal-link, .as-footnotes .as-globalfooter-mini-legal-link{top: -3px; position: relative; z-index: 1;}.as-globalfooter .as-globalfooter-directory+.as-globalfooter-mini, .as-footnotes .as-globalfooter-directory+.as-globalfooter-mini{padding-bottom: 26px;}.container{position: relative;}hr{display: inline-block; border: 0px; border-top: 0.1em solid #CCD2D9; width: 100%}</style></head><body class="page-overview"> <nav data-store-api="/shop/bag/status" id="ac-globalnav"> <div class="ac-gn-content"> <ul class="ac-gn-list"> <a href="/" class="ac-gn-link ac-gn-link-apple"> <p class="ac-gn-link-text">Apple</p></a> <a href="/us/shop/goto/store" class="ac-gn-link ac-gn-link-store"> <p class="ac-gn-link-text">Store</p></a> <a href="/mac/" class="ac-gn-link ac-gn-link-mac"> <p class="ac-gn-link-text">Mac</p></a> <a href="/ipad/" class="ac-gn-link ac-gn-link-ipad"> <p class="ac-gn-link-text">iPad</p></a> <a href="/iphone/" class="ac-gn-link ac-gn-link-iphone"> <p class="ac-gn-link-text">iPhone</p></a> <a href="/watch/" class="ac-gn-link ac-gn-link-watch"> <p class="ac-gn-link-text">Watch</p></a> <a href="/airpods/" class="ac-gn-link ac-gn-link-airpods"> <p class="ac-gn-link-text">AirPods</p></a> <a href="/tv-home/" class="ac-gn-link ac-gn-link-tvhome"> <p class="ac-gn-link-text">TV &amp; Home</p></a> 
<a href="/services/" class="ac-gn-link ac-gn-link-onlyonapple"> <p class="ac-gn-link-text">Only on Apple</p></a> <a href="/us/shop/goto/buy_accessories" class="ac-gn-link ac-gn-link-accessories"> <p class="ac-gn-link-text">Accessories</p></a> <a href="https://support.apple.com" class="ac-gn-link ac-gn-link-support"> <p class="ac-gn-link-text">Support</p></a> <li class="ac-gn-item ac-gn-item-menu ac-gn-search"> <a id="ac-gn-link-search" class="ac-gn-link ac-gn-link-search" href="/us/search" data-analytics-title="search" data-analytics-intrapage-link="" aria-label="Search apple.com" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"></a> </li><a href="/us/shop/goto/bag" class="ac-gn-link ac-gn-link-bag"> <p class="ac-gn-link-text">Shopping Bag</p></a> </ul> </div></nav> <div id="ac-gn-placeholder"> </div><main id="main" class="main" role="main" data-page-type="overview"> <h1 class="section-headline typography-headline">The page you’re looking for can’t be found.</h1> <aside id="search-wrapper" role="search" data-analytics-region="search" aria-hidden="false"> <form id="searchform-form" class="searchform" action="/us/search" method="get" data-suggestions-url="/search-services/suggestions/"><input id="searchform-input" type="text" class="form-textbox form-textbox-text form-icon-left" aria-labelledby="textbox_label" required="" aria-required="true" data-placeholder-long="Search for Products, Stores, and Help" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off"><span class="form-label" id="textbox_label" aria-hidden="true">Search apple.com</span> <div id="searchform-submit" class="form-icons-wrapper form-icons-wrapper-left form-icons-focusable" type="submit" aria-label="Submit"><button class="form-icons form-icons-search15"></button></div><div id="searchform-reset" class="button-reset form-icons-wrapper form-icons-focusable" type="reset" disabled="" aria-label="Clear Search"><button class="form-icons form-icons-small form-icons-clearsolid15 form-icon-reset"></button></div></form> </aside> <div class="cta-sitemap"> <div class="cta-sitemap"> <a href="/sitemap/" class="more" style="top: bottom">Or see our site map</a> </div></div></main> <footer class="as-globalfooter as-globalfooter-contained"> <div class="as-globalfooter-content"> <div class="as-globalfooter-breadcrumbs"> <a href="/" class="as-globalfooter-breadcrumbs-home"> <p class="as-globalfooter-breadcrumbs-home-icon"></p><p class="as-globalfooter-breadcrumbs-home-label">Apple</p></a> <div class="as-globalfooter-breadcrumbs-path"> <ol class="as-globalfooter-breadcrumbs-list"> <li class="as-globalfooter-breadcrumbs-item breadcrumbs-title"> Page Not Found</li></ol> </div></div><nav class="as-globalfooter-directory with-5-columns"> <div class="as-globalfooter-directory-column"> <div class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section"> <h3 class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section-title">Shop and Learn</h3> <ul class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section-list"> <a href="/us/shop/goto/store">Store</a> <a href="/mac/">Mac</a> <a href="/ipad/">iPad</a> <a href="/iphone/">iPhone</a> <a href="/watch/">Watch</a> <a href="/airpods/">AirPods</a> <a href="/tv-home/">TV &amp; Home</a> <a href="/ipod-touch/">iPod touch</a> <a href="/airtag/">AirTag</a> <a href="/us/shop/goto/buy_accessories">Accessories</a> <a href="/us/shop/goto/giftcards">Gift Cards</a> </ul> </div></div><div class="as-globalfooter-directory-column"> <div class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section"> <h3 class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section-title">Services</h3> <ul class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section-list"> <a href="/apple-music/">Apple Music</a> <a href="/apple-tv-plus/">Apple TV+</a> <a href="/apple-fitness-plus/">Apple Fitness+</a> <a href="/apple-news/">Apple News+</a> <a href="/apple-arcade/">Apple Arcade</a> <a href="/icloud/">iCloud</a> <a href="/apple-one/">Apple One</a> <a href="/apple-card/">Apple Card</a> <a href="/apple-books/">Apple Books</a> <a href="/apple-podcasts/">Apple Podcasts</a> <a href="/app-store/">App Store</a> </ul> </div><div class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section"> <h3 class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section-title">Account</h3> <ul class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section-list"> <a href="https://appleid.apple.com/us/">Manage Your Apple ID</a> <a href="/us/shop/goto/account">Apple Store Account</a> <a href="https://www.icloud.com">iCloud.com</a> </ul> </div></div><div class="as-globalfooter-directory-column"> <div class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section"> <h3 class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section-title">Apple Store</h3> <ul class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section-list"> <a href="/retail/">Find a Store</a> <a href="/retail/geniusbar/">Genius Bar</a> <a href="/today/">Today at Apple</a> <a href="/today/camp/">Apple Camp</a> <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/id375380948">Apple Store App</a> <a href="/us/shop/goto/special_deals">Refurbished and Clearance</a> <a href="/us/shop/goto/payment_plan">Financing</a> <a href="/us/shop/goto/trade_in">Apple Trade In</a> <a href="/us/shop/goto/order/list">Order Status</a> <a href="/us/shop/goto/help">Shopping Help</a> </ul> </div></div><div class="as-globalfooter-directory-column"> <div class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section"> <h3 class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section-title">For Business</h3> <ul class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section-list"> <a href="/business/">Apple and Business</a> <a href="/retail/business/">Shop for Business</a> </ul> </div><div class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section"> <h3 class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section-title">For Education</h3> <ul class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section-list"> <a href="/education/">Apple and Education</a> <a href="/education/k12/how-to-buy/">Shop for K-12</a> <a href="/us/shop/goto/educationrouting">Shop for College</a> </ul> </div><div class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section"> <h3 class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section-title">For Healthcare</h3> <ul class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section-list"> <a href="/healthcare/">Apple in Healthcare</a> <a href="/healthcare/apple-watch/">Health on Apple Watch</a> <a href="/healthcare/health-records/">Health Records on iPhone</a> </ul> </div><div class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section"> <h3 class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section-title">For Government</h3> <ul class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section-list"> <a href="/r/store/government/">Shop for Government</a> <a href="/us/shop/goto/eppstore/veteransandmilitary">Shop for Veterans and Military</a> </ul> </div></div><div class="as-globalfooter-directory-column"> <div class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section"> <h3 class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section-title">Apple Values</h3> <ul class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section-list"> <a href="/accessibility/">Accessibility</a> <a href="/education/connectED/">Education</a> <a href="/environment/">Environment</a> <a href="/diversity/">Inclusion and Diversity</a> <a href="/privacy/">Privacy</a> <a href="/racial-equity-justice-initiative/">Racial Equity 
and Justice</a> <a href="/supplier-responsibility/">Supplier Responsibility</a> </ul> </div><div class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section"> <h3 class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section-title">About Apple</h3> <ul class="as-globalfooter-directory-column-section-list"> <a href="/newsroom/">Newsroom</a> <a href="/leadership/">Apple Leadership</a> <a href="/careers/us/">Career Opportunities</a> <a href="https://investor.apple.com">Investors</a> <a href="/compliance/">Ethics &amp; Compliance</a> <a href="/apple-events/">Events</a> <a href="/contact/">Contact Apple</a> </ul> </div></div></nav> <div class="as-globalfooter-mini"> <div class="as-globalfooter-mini-shop">More ways to shop: 
<a href="/retail/">Find an Apple Store</a> or <a href="https://locate.apple.com/">other retailer</a> near you. <span>Or call 1-800-MY-APPLE.</span> </div><div class="as-globalfooter-mini-locale"> <a class="as-globalfooter-mini-locale-link" href="/choose-country-region/" title="Choose your country or region" aria-label="United States. Choose your country or region" data-analytics-title="choose your country">United States</a> </div><p class="as-globalfooter-mini-legal-copyright">Copyright © 2022 Apple Inc. All rights reserved. </p><a class="as-globalfooter-mini-legal-link" href="/legal/privacy/">Privacy Policy </a> <a class="as-globalfooter-mini-legal-link" href="/legal/internet-services/terms/site.html">Terms of Use </a> <a class="as-globalfooter-mini-legal-link" href="/us/shop/goto/help/sales_refunds">Sales 
and Refunds </a> <a class="as-globalfooter-mini-legal-link" href="/legal/">Legal </a> <a class="as-globalfooter-mini-legal-link" href="/sitemap/">Site Map </a> </div></div></footer> <script src="https://www.apple.com/v/errors/c/built/scripts/main.built.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script></body></html>
```

Comment: What error? Post the full error here. I could run your sample with `headless=True` without issues.

Comment: @Charchit tks for the ask! The error was added in the question

Comment: Like I said, this seems to work just fine for me with headless. Can you add `print(html)` right before `soup=...` so we can see what content the site is responding with specifically to you?

Comment: @Charchit tks! `print(html)` added in the question. It looks like it can't find the page...

Answer (score 3):

First of all, Playwright already has a full suite of selectors that work on the live page, so to eliminate a dependency, speed up your scrape, use less code and avoid weird errors when the static HTML snapshot gets out of sync with the live page, I suggest [skipping BS](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#using-a-separate-html-parser-with-puppeteer) (this blog post of mine is oriented to Puppeteer/Node, but applies equally to Playwright/Python).

On to the main problem, you've done good by printing the HTML to see what sort of response you're dealing with. The 404 page indicates you've been detected as a bot when running headlessly, but this can often manifest as a captcha, Cloudflare browser check page, or other "are you a robot?" notice.

As with everything in scraping, there's no one-size-fits-all solution, but one typical approach is to set a custom user agent string:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True)
    ua = (
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) "
        "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
        "Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"
    )
    url = (
        "https://www.apple.com/br/shop/product/MV7N2BE/A/airpods-com-estojo-de-recarga"
    )
    page = browser.new_page(user_agent=ua)
    page.goto(url, wait_until="domcontentloaded")
    sel = "span.as-price-installments:last-child"
    text = (
        page.wait_for_selector(sel)
        .text_content()
        .replace("à vista (10% de desconto)", "")
        .strip()
    )
    print(text)  # => R$ 1.399,50
    browser.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, @ggorlen. Your explanation of the reason for the error makes a lot of sense, I believe that's what it is. I copied exactly the code you sent and tried to run it but it returned an error.
`
playwright._impl._api_types.TimeoutError: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for selector "span.as-price-installments:last-child" to be visible
=========================================================
`

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Can you provide additional info? Dump of `page.content()`/location you're running this from?

Comment: `page.content()`  it's too long and doesn't fit the question... but I tried to use the same code as you

Comment: No need to post it, but on your end, can you look at it and see what it's returning? What location are you running this from?

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html><html class="br pt pt-br amr js seg-consumer no-supports-applepay no-supports-apw svg no-touch no-ie no-oldie no-ios supports-animation supports-columns supports-backdrop-filter no-supports-ar as-mouseuser" lang="pt-BR"><head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
    <title>Comprar AirPods (2ª&nbsp;geração) - Apple (BR)</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">    
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">`
Do you think it might have something to do with "no-supports"?

Comment: Doubt it. Not sure what the problem is. Maybe try running it on repl.it or some other cloud site so the request isn't going from your local server. You still haven't provided your location (although there's probably not much that I can offer, mostly just curious).

Comment: In page.content() i find the element "<span class="as-prices-installments as-price-installments">"
I running this in Brazil-SP

Comment: Then you should be good... I don't see how it would fail to select that, although you could try another selector. What Python and Playwright versions are you on? I'm on Py 3.10.2 and Playwright 1.23.1.

Comment: Py 3.8.10 and playwright 1.22.0
I try run this in repl.it, but dont works... In cloud execution need use async mode... For this i need more time hehehehe

Comment: Yeah, I mean, the response seems to be coming through fine and the element is there, so I don't understand why it wouldn't select. Although I don't recommend BS when using Playwright, maybe try your original code but with the UA string and see if BS can select it. Best to use lxml with BS, BTW.

Comment: Using BS, html.parser and the UA string with the original code, worked perfectly!
Thank you very much! Your knowledge is incredible! (I will study more about lxml before using it.)