# playwright does not render JS scripts and hence the HTML is not fully loaded

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright, playwright-python

I'm using python playwright package to load a website to scrape some data but the page isn't fully loading. When I print the page content, all i see is script tags and pretty much nothing else, even the screenshot is a blank picture. I searched and searched but I couldn't find anything on this. Does anyone know a way to load the page properly?

My code (still in debug/dev stages):

```
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright, Browser, Playwright, Page
import asyncio

async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as P:
        browser = await P.chromium.launch(channel='chrome')
        page = await browser.new_page()
        await page.goto('https://www.bvl.com.pe/mercado/movimientos-diarios')
        # Literally the only possible fix i found online
        await page.keyboard.press('PageDown')
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        print(await page.content())
        await page.screenshot(path="screenshot.png", full_page=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main_main())
```

Comment: Did you try running with `headless=False` or adding a user agent string? You're probably being detected as a bot. Typo: `main_main` should be `main`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Headless doesn't work using Playwright and BeautifulSoup 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72887356/headless-doesnt-work-using-playwright-and-beautifulsoup-4)

Comment: @ggorlen holy poop you were right! i added user agent and its fully loaded now! thank you very much.
Edit: About edit: i slipped my mind!

Answer (score 1):

Every time I have to use the code generator feature before scraping a web page by Playwright. I think you haven't waited long enough, the website hasn't loaded yet. This is the code used to fix (I added headless to make it easier to follow). If you use a code generator, you can do many other actions, like pressing accept cookies, disappearing some popups, so the image will be more accurate.

```
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright, Browser, Playwright, Page
import asyncio

async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as P:
        browser = await P.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        
        # context = await browser.new_context()
        # page = await context.new_page()
        
        page = await browser.new_page()

        await page.goto('https://www.bvl.com.pe/mercado/movimientos-diarios')
        await page.wait_for_timeout(5000)
        await page.keyboard.press('PageDown')
        await page.wait_for_timeout(2000)
        await page.screenshot(path="screenshot.png", full_page=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```