# Error in Playwright using Python: playwright._impl._api_types.Error: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR at

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I'm learning a bit of web scraping using Playwright and Python, but I can't connect to the website I wish to using goto.

```python
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

def run(playwright):
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=True)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto('https://www.tesla.com/de_DE/inventory/new/ms?arrangeby=relevance&range=0',timeout = 0)
    browser.close()

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    run(playwright)
```

The error I get is:
playwright._impl._api_types.Error: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR at https://www.tesla.com/de_DE/inventory/new/ms?arrangeby=relevance&range=0

Along with it there's a single line of logs:
navigating to "https://www.tesla.com/de_DE/inventory/new/ms?arrangeby=relevance&range=0", waiting until "load"

I tried adding timeout=0 to the goto but I get the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Headless doesn't work using Playwright and BeautifulSoup 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72887356/headless-doesnt-work-using-playwright-and-beautifulsoup-4)

Comment: The site is likely detecting you as a robot and blocking you. Try `headless=False` or add a user agent, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72999870/6243352). Never use `timeout=0` because it just makes the error harder to see and fix, turning it effecrtively into a silent infinite loop, and doesn't fundamentally change the behavior. If the navigation doesn't resolve in 30 seconds or a minute at the most, it'll never resolve.