# My playwright-python test results in different HTML for headed vs headless mode

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I'm getting a significantly different page / HTML when I run in headed mode vs headless mode. Running in headed mode of course is replicating the experience I see when using the UI manually.

Here's the HTML element I'm most concerned with, headless vs headed (scroll to right):

```
<button aria-label="Add to bag. This button will add the item to your bag and open a dialog window. After opening press tab to move context to dialog." class="add-to-bag-with-price add-to-bag-with-selected-size pdp-mfe-ya50ik" id="AddToBag_add-to-bag__button">


<button aria-label="Add to bag. This button will add the item to your bag and open a dialog window. After opening press tab to move context to dialog." class="add-to-bag-with-price add-to-bag-with-selected-size pdp-mfe-ya50ik" id="AddToBag_add-to-bag__button" disabled="">
```

Here's the screenshot I had the script take for headless mode:

[image]

Here's a screengrab of the screenshot I had the script take for headed mode (since that original screenshot is over 2MB, I can't upload it here):
[image]

Note that the "Fit: True to size" meter is only displayed in headed mode (just above the 'Add to Bag' button). More importantly, in headed mode, 'Add to Bag' button is disabled (since the item is out of stock in that size). In headless mode, that button is enabled (as you can see in the screenshot and in the HTML), and I do not understand why. My script runs the following line:

```
if page.get_by_label("Add to bag", exact=False).is_enabled():
```

which of course is giving me False during headed mode, and True during headless mode.

Here's the full python file being run via `pytest` command (test_check_size_in_stock is the only test):

```
import pytest
from playwright.sync_api import Page, expect


def open_page(page: Page) -> None:
    page.goto("https://bananarepublic.gap.com/browse/product.do?pid=2666360923230")


def close_dynamic_modals(page: Page) -> None:
    if page.get_by_test_id("dynamic-modal-content").is_visible():
        print('closing promotional modal')
        page.get_by_label("close email sign up modal").click()  # this label is used for multiple different modals

    if page.get_by_label("Close Survey", exact=True).is_visible():
        print('closing survey modal')
        page.get_by_label("Close Survey", exact=True).click()


# this fixture will run before every test
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def start(page: Page):
    open_page(page)
    close_dynamic_modals(page)


def test_check_size_in_stock(page: Page):
    # Make sure we're at the right product page
    expect(page.get_by_role("heading", name="Skinny Traveler Pant")).to_be_visible()

    # Choose the pants color: Black
    page.get_by_label("Black", exact=True).check()

    # Click on waist size "32W" NOTE: when out of stock, the label = "Size:32W out of stock" so using exact=False
    page.get_by_label("Size:32W", exact=False).click()

    # Click on length size "30L" NOTE: when out of stock, the label = "Size:30L out of stock" so using exact=False
    page.get_by_label("Size:30L", exact=False).click()

    # Now that the desired size is selected, determine if it's in stock
    # 'Add to Bag' button will be disabled if it's not in stock NOTE: the label is a long sentence so using exact=False
    page.screenshot(path='screenshot_headless.png', full_page=True)
    if page.get_by_label("Add to bag", exact=False).is_enabled():
        print("In stock!")
        assert True
    else:
        print("Out of stock!")
        assert False

    # page.screenshot(path='screenshot_headless.png')
```

Comment: Did you try [adding a user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72999870/6243352)?

Comment: @ggorlen that seems to have resolved this for me. thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Headless doesn't work using Playwright and BeautifulSoup 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72887356/headless-doesnt-work-using-playwright-and-beautifulsoup-4)